# Parse iOS Swift Push Notification History

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, notifications

I am using Parse Push Notifications with Swift (iOS 8). The problem is when app is closed and you recieve multiple notifications, they will show in notifications alert. When I touch one of the notification it will open my app......but it will clear all notifications in notification alert view (not sure what is called). So as result all of my push notifications are lost. And I need them since they have specific payload that my app needs.

So basicly, all I need is data from received notification (not just from the one I opened).

I am using this code that Parse recommends. When app is closed and is opened with push, this function is called. I use constant let = notificationPayload to get info of payloads from push notifications. But I only get data from one push.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore. 
    // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // ****************************************************************************
    // Uncomment this line if you want to enable Crash Reporting
    // ParseCrashReporting.enable()
    //
    // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:
    Parse.setApplicationId("+++++", clientKey: "++++++++")


    //
    // If you are using Facebook, uncomment and add your FacebookAppID to your bundle's plist as
    // described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/
    // Uncomment the line inside ParseStartProject-Bridging-Header and the following line here:
    // PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
    // ****************************************************************************

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        // Extract the notification data.
           if let notificationPayload = launchOptions?       [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
    // notificationPayload have payload of only one push notification.
  }

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

    return true
}
```

Any goot info, webpage, tutorial for this? Parse.com documentation is useless since apparently people get only one notification when app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If your push notifications contain important payload, you will probably have to save that payload somewhere else (Parse cloud data, for instance).

This way, even if iOS ditches your push notifications (or if the user decided to discard them) - your payload will be always available.

When the application starts up - look up for that payload in the database and act accordingly.

Comment: Is there a way that my app would react to push notification even when is completly closed (not just in background)? Because that would be perfect. But I was under impression that when app is closed, there is no way for push to activate some code of my app.

Comment: Nope that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was causing my Notifications to disappeare. I had this code in which would erase notifications:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```